# Delete local tag fails

Tags: mercurial, tags

I'm trying to delete a local tag in a Mercurial repo using:

```
hg tag --remove tag-name
```

and I get the following message:

> abort: tag 'last-working' is not a global tag

Is there a way to delete local tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
hg tag --remove --local tag-name
```